# UiSlider should be updated inside UITableviewCell every second

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a requirement where I need to show the slider in the UITableview's cell. It is basically a download table view where audio items keep downloading, the progress of download is captured and shown in tableview's cell. Every time the download of item happens, I receive a delegate method and that I call reload table to update the table view. This is leading to a scrolling issue where table doesn't scroll smoothy as it will reloading the cell for item download. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Accid Bright](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18467493/2613662) is definitely on the right track with this and could probably be a more than acceptable solution. However if you are still seeing performance issues it could be that the cells are still doing too much work when they are being reloaded. What I'd look at doing is updating only the value of the `UISlider`:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = /* index path to the current row to be updated */
MyCustomCell *cell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.slider setValue:DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS animated:NO];
```

On an unrelated note I'd suggest you look at using `UIProgressView` instead of `UISlider` as it's more appropriate for displaying progress.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
// indexPaths array contains NSIndexPath of you cell with UISlider.
NSArray * indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPath:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

can help you. This allows to update only some rows, not all table.

Even if it doesn't solve the problem, it's better to update only one row, that you need rather then every second reload all data to table.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4
Very easy way just use it,  just copy past the code and enjoy

```
@objc func sliderUpdate(slider: UISlider){
//MARK:- Add new row in table view
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: slider.tag, section: 0)
    let cell = self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as!  MessagingSenderCell  */MARK:- User user cell name because i am using the MessagingSenderCell for chat and i have use the slider for send a voice message/*
    let cmTime = CMTime(seconds: audioPlayer.duration, preferredTimescale: 1000000)

     let duration : CMTime = cmTime
     var seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

     self.tableview.beginUpdates()
     cell.slider.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
     self.slidertimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.25, repeats: true) { timer in
                seconds -= 0.25
                if seconds <= 0 {
                    //print("Go!")
                    self.slidertimer.invalidate()
                    cell.slider.setValue(0, animated: false)
                    self.tablev.endUpdates()
                } else {
                   // print(self.responds)
                   //print("Slider: " + "\(self.sliderr.value)")
                   //print("Player: " + "\(self.audioPlayer.currentTime)")

                    cell.slider.setValue(Float(self.audioPlayer.currentTime), animated: false)
                }
            }


}
```